# DVR access over internet

Tags: router, internet, internet-connection, dvr

So, there are: 1. analogue cameras, 2. DVR, 3. network router, 4. hikvision app installed on android phone. My question is how to setup " these things" so I can access, view, replay content on my DVR? If I am not in my local network, how to access DVR through router? When I open hikvision app " add device" there is: Alias: ; register mode: I choose IP/domain; address: ; port: ; user name: ; password: ; . In register mode there are 3 options: HiDDNS, Ip/domain, IP Server. I want directly to access my dvr content through my router, but how to do that when I am not in my local network?

Comment: Do you have a dynamic or a static external IP?

Comment: Dyamic IP address. What options I have ? I know for dynDNS but what else is possible? Can I somehow directly access my DVR? PC/ phone - internet- my router - DVR ? And how to set up?

Comment: You should use a dynamicDNS, so that your DVR will be reachable from your external network without it being dependent on your IP address.

Comment: Your DVR needs to have a static local IP, and you need to forward a port on your router to the port of your DVR's local IP.